# How to remove an item from repeated list in Android proto DataStore?

Tags: android, proto, android-jetpack-datastore

Here is the proto file with the definition for a list of strings.

```
message MyMessages {
    repeated string message = 1;
}
```

Here is the function for removing a message from the repeated message list.

```
suspend fun removeMsg(msg : String) {
    myMessagesStore.updateData { myMessages ->
        val existingMessages = myMessages.toBuilder().messageList;
        if (existingMessages.contains(msg)) {
            existingMessages.remove(msg)
            myMessages.toBuilder().clear().addAllMessage(existingMessages).build()
        } else {
            myMessages
        }
    }
}
```

When the above code runs, it crashed on `existingMessages.remove(msg)` with the error:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
        at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.remove
```

existingMessages is a MutableList which contains the remove function, why is this crashing on this and what's the proper way to remove an item from a repeated list item in proto DataStore?

**Updates**:
existingMessages is

```
/**
 * <code>repeated string message = 1;</code>
 * @return A list containing the message.
 */
@java.lang.Override
public java.util.List<java.lang.String>
    getMessageList() {
  return java.util.Collections.unmodifiableList(
      instance.getMessageList());
}
```

It looks like the generated class from proto is making the repeated list unmodfiableList. Then my question is why there isn't a `myMessages.toBuilder().removeMessage(newMessage)` function from the generated class similar to the addMessage function such as this:

```
myMessages.toBuilder().addMessage(newMessage)
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you please post the exact data type of `existingMessages`.

I am not an expert in proto DataStore, so please correct me incase I am wrong.
As per the exception message, there could be few main reason behind the crash:

1. The `existingMessages` is immutable list. As per the exception, we can see that the name of the collection is `java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection`.
2. The `existingMessages` is a custom mutable list, which haven't implemented the `#remove` function.

To fix this, you can choose one of the following approach based on your guidelines:

1. Update the type of `messageList` in Builder class as MutableList for other external classes.
2. In case you are using custom implementation of list and the `#remove` is not implemented, please implement it.
3. In case you can't change the return type of `messageList`, simply use `#filter` method to copy and skip the required message as follow:

```
existingMessages.filter { it != msg }
```

Comment: yes, it is indeed an UnmodifiableCollection and I've updated my question to why there isn't a remove function from the generated class from proto